# HttpHandler not always firing for MVC 4 Web API app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, httphandler

I am trying to write a custom IHttpHandler to authenticate users calling an ASP.NET Web API app:

```
public class AuthenticationHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var id = context.Request.QueryString["id"];

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id))
        {
            return;
        }

        var key = context.Request.QueryString["key"];
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key))
        {
            return;
        }

        using (var db = new DataContext())))
        { 
            var client = db.Clients.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ApiId == id);
            if (client == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (!client.ApiKeys.Any(x => x.Key == key))
            {
                return;
            }

            context.User = new ApiPrincipal
            {
                Identity = new ApiIdentity
                {
                    IsAuthenticated = true,
                    Name = client.Name,
                    ClientId = client.Id
                }
            };

            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = context.User;
        }
    }
}
```

My Web.config section looks like this:

```
<system.webServer>
 <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
 <handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="AuthenticationHandler" path="*" verb="*" type="AuthenticationHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

AuthenticationHandler is my custom handler. It does work on the root page, i.e. http://example.com/, but not otherwise. If any route is specified, i.e. http://example.com/MyApiController, ProcessRequest is never run.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: (Just to say)... a more appropriate approach for WebApi is to use a MessageHandler (Delegating Handler) rather than an HttpHandler. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-message-handlers

Comment: Also using `HttpHandler` for authentication might not be what you are looking for as `HttpHandler` act as a target for the incoming HTTP requests (so only one is executed). You might want to take a look at `HttpModule` because those are being called for all requests. Read more here [HTTP Handlers and HTTP Modules in ASP.NET](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/article.php/c19389/HTTP-Handlers-and-HTTP-Modules-in-ASPNET.htm)

Comment: @MarkJones After more research, I agree with you. It still bugs me that the HTTP Handler won't work, but I'll probably just dump it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you should to register the handler in "internal" Web.config, in Views folder. It looks something like this:

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>
```